# How to move a struct into a class?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I've got something like:

```
typedef struct Data_s {
  int field1;
  int field2;
} Data;

class Foo {
  void getData(Data& data);
  void useData(Data& data);
}
```

In another class's function, I might do:

```
class Bar {
  Data data_;
  void Bar::taskA() {
    Foo.getData(data_);
    Foo.useData(data_);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to move the Data out of the global scope and into Foo without creating a new class? Data mirrors a struct existing in a library I'm using elsewhere. (i.e. same fields, just different name. I cast Data into the other struct later. I do this because Foo is an abstract class, and the derived class using the library is just one of many.)

Currently, just pasting it inside the class and replacing `Data` with `Foo::Data` everywhere doesn't work.

```
class Foo {
  typedef struct Data_s {
    int field1;
    int field2;
  } Data;
  ...
}
```

I get `'Data' in class 'Foo' does not name a type` at `Bar data_;`

Comment: So you want to create a class which is similar to Data_s? Or you want to copy its members' values at runtime into a class?

Comment: There are only a few differences between struct and class, what are you trying to achieve by 'moving struct to class' ? Probably some clarification about what exactly are you trying to do would help.

Comment: Added/clarified. Is that better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the struct inside the class, but you need to do it ahead of the place where you first use it. Structs, like classes themselves, must be forward-declared in order to use them:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    struct Data
    {
        int field1;
        int field2;
    };

    void getData(Foo::Data& data) {}
    void useData(Foo::Data& data) {}
};

void UseFooData()
{
    Foo::Data bar;
    Foo f;
    f.getData(bar);
    f.useData(bar);
}
```

Edit: Updated example to use the same fields/class names as listed in the original question. Please note that in order to be visible outside of the `Foo` class, `Data` needs to be declared `public` and other code needs to reference it as `Foo::Data`.

Comment: Since the question has struct Data_s and class Foo, can you revise your answer in terms of those?

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, Foo::Data isn't accessible in the code snippet you gave.  Class members default to private visibility.

Secondly, when you're using C++, typedef for structure declarations is NOT recommended (there are other valid uses, but your usage is not).

Try this corrected version instead:

```
class Foo {
public:
  struct Data {
    int field1;
    int field2;
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: just curious, when is typedef for structure declarations recommended then?

Comment: Never in C++.  In C, if you didn't use a typedef, you'd have to say "struct that" everywhere, the typedef lets you say just "that".  With C++ you don't need the struct, so the typedef is useless.  Typedef has other uses, especially in the presence of templates, but typedef on a class or struct definition is a quick way to spot a C programmer with zero C++ experience.

Comment: Actually, I was doing that only b/c I was following the example of the minizip and unrar libraries, which are written in C. @.@